# Power of functions, cannot find function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$. Define $f: A\to A$ by $f(1) = 2$, $f(2) = 1$, and $f(3) = 3$.

Find $f^2$, $f^3$, $f^4$, and $f^{-1}$.

I understand that to find the power functions is simply function composition, but I can't find a function to fit these data points. Am I missing something obvious? I feel like this should be an easy problem to solve.

Comment: maybe this could help you $f^2(1)=f(f(1))=f(2)=1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f^2$ is the identity function.

Comment: So that means f^2 and f^4 are both identify functions because they will always equal what was inputted in them? Also, that means f^inverse is equal to f^3?

Comment: Yes. And what are $f^3$ and the inverse of $f$, if $f^2$ is the identity function?

Comment: f^3 and the inverse of f are both equal to f then!!?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.